# Problema con borrar los datos en un listView

Tags: java, android-studio

buenas tengo un problema con el listView. Quiero ir añadiendo una serie de personas al listView y cuando mantengo pulsada a una persona que se elimine del listView. Mi problema viene de que cuando elimino esa persona realmente sí se elimina pero en el listView siempre se borra la última persona que he añadido.
Por ejemplo, si tengo a Ismael, Lucía y Pepe y borro a Ismael, en la pantalla se me quedan Ismael y Lucía. Si pulso en Ismael me salen los datos de Lucía y si pulso en Lucía me salen los datos de Pepe.
Me gustaría saber como resolver el problema de mostrar correctamente los datos en el listView.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.ejsexamen2;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button btnAgnadir;
    EditText etNombre, etFecha;

    ListView lv;
    RadioButton rb1, rb2;

    //Declaramos la lista donde vamos a guardar las personas y su adaptador personalizado
    ArrayList<Persona> miLista = new ArrayList<>();
    PersonaAdaptador mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.listaPersonas);

        etNombre = findViewById(R.id.escribe_nombre) ;
        etFecha = findViewById(R.id.escribe_fecha);
        btnAgnadir = findViewById(R.id.boton_agnadir);
        rb1 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton_ordenarNombre);
        rb2 = findViewById(R.id.radioButton_ordenarFecha);

        /*Persona p1 = new Persona("ismael", "19/06/2001");
        miLista.add(p1);*/

        mAdapter = new PersonaAdaptador(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listview, miLista);


        btnAgnadir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String nombre = etNombre.getText().toString();
                String fecha = etFecha.getText().toString();
                Persona p = new Persona(nombre, fecha);
                miLista.add(p);

                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                //etNombre.getText().clear();
                //etFecha.getText().clear();
                if(rb1.isChecked()) {

                }
                else if(rb2.isChecked()) {

                }
            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Persona p = miLista.get(i);
                DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
                LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.parse(p.getFechaNacimiento(), fmt);
                LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();

                Period periodo = Period.between(fechaNac, ahora);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Nombre: " + p.getNombre() +
                                " tu edad es " + periodo.getYears() + "  " + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                final int posicion = i;
                miLista.remove(posicion);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hola" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

PersonaAdaptador.java

```
package com.example.ejsexamen2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.List;

public class PersonaAdaptador extends ArrayAdapter<Persona> {
    //Declaramos la lista, el contexto y el resource
    private List<Persona> lista;
    private Context mContext;
    private int ressourceLayout;

    //Constructor
    public PersonaAdaptador(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Persona> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.lista = objects;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.ressourceLayout = resource;
    }

    //Vista
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView; //Inicialimos la vista
        if(view == null) {  //Si es nula
            //Le ponemos el layoutInflater con el contexto y su respectiva vista
            //He usado el resourceLayout pero podría haber usado R.layout.list_view
            view  = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(ressourceLayout, null);

            //inicialimos el deporte mediante la posición en la lista
            Persona p = lista.get(position);

            //Inicializamos los elementos

            TextView textoNombre = view.findViewById(R.id.texto_personaNombre);
            textoNombre.setText(p.getNombre());

            TextView textoFecha = view.findViewById(R.id.texto_personaFecha);
            textoFecha.setText((CharSequence) p.getFechaNacimiento());

        }
        //retornamos la vista
        return view;

    }
}
```

Persona.java

```
package com.example.ejsexamen2;

import java.util.Date;

public class Persona implements Comparable{

    String nombre;
    String fechaNacimiento;

    public Persona(String nombre, String fechaNacimiento) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getFechaNacimiento() {
        return fechaNacimiento;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimiento(String fechaNacimiento) {
        this.fechaNacimiento = fechaNacimiento;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Persona p = (Persona) o;
        if (this.nombre.compareTo(p.nombre) == -1) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.nombre.compareTo(p.nombre) == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

he investigado un poco y al final he encontrado la solución. En el método onLongItemClick le tengo que volver a poner al listView el adaptador para que la vista cambie y se modifique de forma correcta.

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Persona p = miLista.get(i);
                miLista.remove(p);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Hola" + i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

La línea clave que me faltaba antes es esta:

```
lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```